# Android: Possible to kill a remote callback?

Tags: android, callback, aidl, android-binder

I am using the class RemoteCallbackList in Android, but when I am calling the callback in the remote process, the callback hangs, and then so do my calling thread. Now, is it possible to "kill" the callback and free my process (from another thread in my process), i.e. can I force a RemoteException to happen in my process to disconnect the callback so I can proceed?

Comment: What type of "callback hangs" so you encounter? Waiting endless for something, endless loop? The best way would be to change the remote process code to make it more robust.

Comment: The remote process dies due to wasting memory, and we need to be resilient against flawed applications either way.

Comment: Assuming you have a thread in your local application that waits for the callback the correct way to handle this situation would be execute `Thread.interrupt()` for the waiting thread.

Comment: It is in a remote external application/process though, however.

Answer (score 0):

just Unregister for the Remotecallback, no need to kill the Remotecallabck

unregister( callback ) : Boolean
Remove from the list a callback that was previously added with register. This uses the callback.asBinder() object to correctly find the previous registration. Registrations are not counted; a single unregister call will remove a callback after any number calls to register for it.

Parameters
callback : Object {IInterface}
The callback to be removed from the list. Passing null here will cause a NullPointerException, so you will generally want to check for null before calling.

Returns
Boolean
Returns true if the callback was found and unregistered. Returns false if the given callback was not found on the list. @see register